# Which files need to be modified in order to define an own custom keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I use a Dvorak-base keyboard, specifically defined for the french language, named "bépo". I also use a polytonic greek (ancient greek) keyboard, based on "querty", which I obviously am not satisfied with. So I want to define my own polytonic greek keyboard based on the bépo layout.

For doing that, I would be glad to be able to derive the necessary files from the ones I'm using, but I've not been able to locate them, nor am I able to locate those new files.

Thank you to anybody who will agree to help me.

Arbiel

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do that by editing the /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/gr.

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/gr
```

I'm not sure exactly what you have to edit, though, since I can't understand greek, but the file is very self explanatory.

Don't forget to make a backup of the old gr file and after you are finished moving things around

```
rm -rf /var/lib/xkb/*
```

in order to clear kbd's cache. You may also need to

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

but it wasn't necessary in my case.

I believe there is a more organized way to inherit language keyboard changes/options, but I'm also not experienced with that.

My source here was https://radu.cotescu.com/remapping-keys-in-ubuntu-14.04/